# How do I make a text border or also called "stroke" around text in documents that have text such as Pages, Markup, etc?

Tags: macos, high-sierra, font, text

How do I make a text border or also called "stroke" around text in documents that have text such as Pages, Markup, etc?

I want white text with a black border or "stroke", what program can I use in macOS to accomplish this?

And how would I do it?

It looks like this, for example:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Pages app is the easiest to get this effect, and it’s the same in Numbers / Keynote. To get the following effect:

[image: outline text from Pages.app]

- Format the text to 64 pt
- Format the text color to neutral gray
- Enable Outline - keep the defaults, black line, 1 pt, solid stroke

Answer (score 1):

- Pages: See outline in extra settings.

  > [image]
- Adobe Photoshop or Illustrator.
- But since these are costly, see GIMP

Comment: What version of Pages is that? I have Pages version 7.1

Comment: Its 8.2.1, I'm on Mojave. see if you can online versions of ms office tools